# IOS 8 swift CoreLocation

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator, core-location

Im learning Xcode 6.3 and swift and following a book from apress Beginning Xcode with swift, in chapter 4 when doing the first tab for the location tracker it shows nothing at all and I'm confused. The code for the first tab is this

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class TrackViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var toggleSwitch: UISwitch!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func changeToggle(sender: UISwitch) {

        if toggleSwitch.on {

            self.locationText.text = " "

            if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() == false) {
                self.toggleSwitch.on = false
            }

            if locationManager == nil {
                locationManager = CLLocationManager()
                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
                NSLog("location is on supposely")

            }

            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


        } else {

            if locationManager != nil {
                locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            }
        }

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var location: CLLocation = locations[locations.endIndex - 1] as! CLLocation

        self.locationText.text = location.description

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {

        locationText.text = "failed with error \(error.description)"

    }
}
```

I have activated in the simulator the location services and in info.plist added the NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription and the Privacy - Location..., but nothing happens when toggling the switch I get no feedback that something is on. Any help??

Comment: Is your key really named `SNLocationWhenInUsageDescription`?  If so, that's part of the problem.  It should be `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Comment: Is it really named `...WhenInUsage...`?  It should be `...WhenInUseUsage...`.

Comment: Let me check I can't open Xcode now :s

Comment: Change it there is something really strange going on Xcode is ignoring everything, my break points do nothing.

Comment: One thing was that line so now is asking for permission to use location, but, still does not display anything in the textView.

Comment: Got it, it was sizeToFit() was not being called so everything got chomped :)